# Проблемы с заполнением UICollectionViewCell внутри UITableViewCell (подгружаются не те изображения

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Есть таблица, внутри которой коллекция с горизонтальным скроллом, фото в коллекцию - ссылки из массива данных полученных url запросом, проблемы с переиспользованием ячеек - при скролле постоянно загружаются не те фотки и не в том количестве (prepareForReuse пробовал , не помогает, почему то), что может быть?

Comment: Свой код вывода фоток приложите

Comment: Вот здесь почитайте https://habr.com/ru/post/320152/ Там есть примеры, почему так может быть и как это исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил. Нужно просто перезагружать коллекцию перед заполнением.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).